# Why does my attempt to send a reactive object to the global environment not work?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

The below example code uses a module structure to pass values from the main server to two modules `mod1` and `mod2` where the values are manipulated and passed back and forth between the modules. This is for learning purposes only. Trying to get my head around transmitting data between modules.

I am trying to send the complete `common` object (which I thought is reactive) to the global environment for examining its contents as it evolves. I use the line of code `observe({assign("common_tmp", common, envir = .GlobalEnv)})` in the main server section below, and it returns the following which tells me little:

```
> common_tmp
<ReactiveValues> 
  Values:    colA_mod2, df, mod1_dat, mod2_table, svc 
  Readonly:  FALSE
```

How do I send the complete `common` object to the global environment for examination? So all the contents and embedded values are shown.

Code:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

mod1_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  DTOutput(ns("tbl"))
}

mod1_server <- function(id, common) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    new_dat <- reactive({
      df <- common$df
      svc <- common$svc()
      df * as.numeric(svc)
    })
    
    observe({
      common$mod1_dat <- new_dat()
      common$colA_mod2 <- common$mod2_table$A
    })
    
    output$tbl <- renderDT({
      dat <- new_dat()
      dat$colA_mod2 <- common$colA_mod2 
      dat
    })
  })
}

mod2_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  DTOutput(ns("tbl"))
}

mod2_server <- function(id, common) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    output$tbl <- renderDT({
      mod1_dat <- common$mod1_dat
      dat <- data.frame(mod1_dat + 10) 
      if (!is.null(common$colA_mod2)) {
        dat$colA_mod2_mod1 <- common$colA_mod2 * 100
      }
      common$mod2_table <- dat
      dat
    })
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    DTOutput("table"),
    sliderInput("svc", "", min = 0, max = 10, value = 1),
    mod1_ui("mod1"),
    mod2_ui("mod2")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  common <- reactiveValues(df = data.frame(A = 1:2, B = 3:4))
  output$table <- renderDT({datatable(common$df)})
  common$svc <- reactive(input$svc)
  mod1_server("mod1", common)
  mod2_server("mod2", common)
  
  observe({assign("common_tmp", common, envir = .GlobalEnv)})
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Try with `shiny::reactiveValuesToList(common)` instead of `common`.

Comment: Rather than trying to "send" data to the global environment (though I like @stefan's suggestion if you must), why not use `session$userData`?  From [this page](https://shiny.posit.co/r/reference/shiny/1.7.0/session.html): "userData An environment for app authors and module/package authors to store whatever session-specific data they want".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following up on stefan's recommendation, adding the following to the main server section seems does the trick (this is a temporary function as I build out the App, I've seen that assigning to the global environment with `<<-` is considered sloppy):

```
observe({common_tmp <<- shiny::reactiveValuesToList(common)})
```

Then I can see the entire contents of `common` at my convenience, in R studio console. The object `common`, in the full App, gets very long and convoluted and I need to be able to review it easily, download it to XLS for testing, etc.